# Manipulating the query builder - Symfony - APYGRIDBundle

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to query database and display results to the APYDataGridBundle,in Symfony. To accomplish this I am using your sample example https://github.com/APY/APYDataGridBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/grid_configuration/manipulate_query.md

After trying for some time,I cannot display queried results to that grid, Please find the code below,

```
$source = new Entity('AppBundle:Entity');
$grid = $this->get('grid');

$conn = $this->get('database_connection');
$qb = $conn->createQueryBuilder();

$qb->select('id');
$qb->from('Entity');

$q = $qb->getSql();
$stmt = $conn->executeQuery($q);
$items_ids = $stmt->fetchAll( );

$source->manipulateQuery($qb);
$grid->setSource($source);

return $grid->getGridResponse('default/grid.html.twig');
```

Comment: Are you getting results returned?  Are you getting any error messages?  What is your output like?

Comment: All values from entity is displayed in to grid manipulate query method does not seems to have effect